# Password protecting file using .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to protect my index.php file using my .htaccess file.
I have created the .htaccess file and a password file .htpasswd

.htaccess contains :

```
AuthUserFile /home/myserver/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Admin IP Manager"

<Files "index.php">
  Require valid-user
</Files>
```

.htpasswd contains:

```
John:p29cmnwl4a0et
```

So what it is doing is when i try open the file, it prompts me for a username and password, when i fill it in it then prompts me again and continues to do this the whole time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error with your password, try using a MD5 algorithm.
So your username and password would be John:p29cmnwl4a0et, but in the .htpasswd file it would look like this :

```
John:$apr1$b2KjOSh6$Ty6CSXX/mlkVd91zziWHq.
```